# Notebook won't wake up from sleep if the USB port is used

Tags: windows-10, laptop, usb, sleep

I have a HP Pavilion x2. I normally wake it up using the power button, but when the USB port is used (something plugged) it doesn't wake up from sleep. I have to keep pushing the power button for a long time and for several attempts, and then it is a forced startup. This has been the case for months and I'm not sure if I bought it with this problem. It is still on warranty.

Thank you.

Comment: I checked. I have the latest updates. Thanks.

Comment: Do your updates include system BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: I updated the BIOS, but the problem still happens.

Comment: Then it is a heavy bug on HP (likely INTEL) side. You should bring this up to HP customer support. They might already have some workaround.